# Animate nav bar in jQuery to move <li> into neighbouring div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

http://jsfiddle.net/ejbk4xq7/3/

What I'm attempting to do is to animate navigation `<li>`s , and have it poke out over the edge of the `<div class="sidebar">` on mouseover. I'm using the `.animate()` function as shown in the jsfiddle and below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').mouseover(
        function(){
            $(this).animate({ right: '10px' }, 'fast');
        },
        function(){
            $(this).animate({ left: '10px' }, 'fast');
        }
    );
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/a77fgs6g/)?

I added the

```
position:relative
```

and

```
display:block
```

properties of your li elements. And changed your hover-function that the position is reseted on mouseleave.

Answer (score 0):

Change the li position in the css to relative, you cannot move the element position if it's static

```
 ul a li {
   background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/7OQuO25.png);
   z-index: 13;
   padding-right: 22px;
   padding-bottom: 7px;
   padding-left: 12px;
   padding-top: 2px;
   margin-top: 3px;
   position:relative; /***set the position relative**/
}
```

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ejbk4xq7/4/)

Note:

your markup is invalid you should change the menu like this

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#">element</a></li>
</ul>
```